# Mann Whitney U with Imputed Data

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, multiple-imputation

I have a survey data set with missing values and I generated 10 multiple imputations in which the missing values were imputed.  I'd like to compare certain groups in my data set using the Mann-Whitney U.

However, I've been searching how to run this analysis in either SAS or SPSS but didn't find a solution. It seems that these routines don't support multiply imputed data. I can run the MWU test on each imputed data set, however, I don't know how to combine the results. Is there a method similar to Rubin's rule for the MWU?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with Stata. Have you considered just creating rankings, and performing a t-test on them? If I well understand, the two quantities are asymptotically equivalent.